# How to download file via command line in php?

Tags: php, file

I want to paste one script in all my client machine which call php file which is on my server.

Let say my server path is www.google.com/support/lokesh.php

So that I want to put one file to all my client machine at location where it call php file(for example if it call from /home/lalu/myscript.sh) then my php code will put one file(additional.sh) to /home/lalu/additional.sh

below is my code to download file

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('google.com/support/lokesh.txt'));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('/home/lokesh/lalu.txt'));
readfile('/home/lokesh/lalu.txt');
    //for sending mail fif only one user is available   
exit;
```

I want to paste one file location at client machine from where it call server file.

Comment: `header()` is used to send a raw HTTP header. Meaning it's completely ignored by PHP CLI.

Comment: What would that look like to begin with? How do you "download" a file if you're not talking to a server? You either just `echo` the file contents, or you directly `file_put_contents` on disk... And since you're reading from a local file to begin with... what's the point?!

Comment: You can't download a file via command line. You can either directly write it to file system, display the content directly, or email the content somewhere.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934420/apache-php-large-file-download-2gb-failing/22934915#22934915 you shouldn't use `readfile()`, it is slow and will take all your memory fast.

Comment: what do you mean by 'download'? you mean from remote host? using what protocol? http? scp(ssh)? Since you have already access to shell why not to use your shell script to 'download' the file (unless you need its content in the php script at runtime)?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Err... no!? `readfile` is specifically optimised to directly stream a file from disk to stdout, it's *much more efficient* than anything else. *"readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level()."* http://php.net/readfile

Comment: @deceze It might be optimized, but output buffer / stdout are not. "much more efficient than anything else" - I strongly doubt that. Low-level functions are always better (fopen, fread, ...). If you read the question on my linked answer, you'll see that readfile is not the way to go. Output buffers behave differently on each server software also (apache as module, fpm, ...).

Comment: @DanFromGermany `fopen` and `fread` in a loop will run "high level" PHP code and temporarily store chunks of the file in PHP's memory; `readfile` can move that same data using lower-level C functions and/or filesystem/memory mapping techniques. Using `fopen`/`fread` you're basically reimplementing `readfile` in high-level PHP code, which can't be good. – How either solution interacts with buffers is a different unfortunate topic; you should ensure all buffering is off when dumping a file to the web server either way.

Answer (score 5):

One attempt, with a progress bar.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
if (@$argv[1] != null){
  echo "Retrieving http header..."; 
  $header = get_headers("$argv[1]");
  $pp = "0";
  echo json_encode($header, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  $key = key(preg_grep('/\bLength\b/i', $header));
  $type = key(preg_grep('/\bType\b/i', $header));
  $http = substr($header[0], 9, 3);
  $tbytes = @explode(" ",$header[$key])[1];
  $type = @explode("/",explode(" ",$header[$type])[1])[1];
  echo " Target size: ".floor((($tbytes / 1000)/1000))." Mo || ".floor(($tbytes/1000))." Kb";
  $t = explode("/",$argv[1]);
  $remote = fopen($argv[1], 'r');
  $nm = $t[count($t)-1].".$type";
  $local = fopen($nm, 'w');
  $read_bytes = 0;  
  echo PHP_EOL;
  while(!feof($remote)) {
    $buffer = fread($remote, intval($tbytes));
    fwrite($local, $buffer);
    $read_bytes += 2048;
    $progress = min(100, 100 * $read_bytes / $tbytes);
    $progress = substr($progress,0 , 6) *4;
    $shell = 10; /* Progress bar width */ 
    $rt = $shell * $progress / 100;
    echo " \033[35;2m\e[0m Downloading: [".round($progress,3)."%] ".floor((($read_bytes/1000)*4))."Kb ";
    if ($pp === $shell){$pp=0;};
    if ($rt === $shell){$rt=0;};
    echo str_repeat("█",$rt).str_repeat("=",($pp++)).">@\r";
    usleep(1000);
  }
  echo " \033[35;2m\e[0mDone [100%]  ".floor((($tbytes / 1000)/1000))." Mo || ".floor(($tbytes/1000))." Kb   \r";
  echo PHP_EOL;
  fclose($remote);
  fclose($local);
}
```

[image]

The file is build directly into the current folder, not in the temp directory.
This mean the file can be read while downloading. 
If the file type is made to handle that, like most media format do.

To use, pass an url as first argument in the command line.

```
./pget  https://site.download.mp4
```

You know you want to tweek it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the easiest way is:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents('/home/lokesh/lalu.txt');
```

If I correctly understood.

Comment: @LOKESH sorry, what do you mean by 'download'? You can save file using `file_put_contents('/tmp/file', $fileContent)` but if file is already exist in your file system... what purpose?
if you use CLI: Client machine - it is your machine!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. In your download file :

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");  
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");  
header("Cache-Control: private",false);
header("Content-Type: application/".$extension); // you can put here MIME type of your file  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filePath) . "\";" );  
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");  
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filePath));  
set_time_limit(0);  
readfile("$filePath");
```